# pgAdmin 9.5 not showing all databases

Tags: pgadmin, postgresql-9.5

I have a problem with my database. I installed PostgreSQL 9.5 on my Ubuntu server. I changed the *postgresql.conf* file to allow binding the PostgreSQL server to the localhost. This allows me to run pgAdmin and connect to my database by forwarding also the port 5432, where I run my PostgreSQL.

The problem I am experiencing is that I only see the default table 'postgres', but not my newly created one 'games'. I created this table by running `postgres=# create database games;` with the postgres user connected to the server. I know the database was created, because if I run `postgres=# \l+` while connected to the server, I get a list of databases, including my 'games'.

In the second picture is my screenshot of the pgAdmin 9.5 application with all the property values I use to connect to my server. So I manage to connect to the server, but I am unable to see the database 'games'.

[image]

I also went a step further and granted all permissions to the postgres user by executing `postgres=# grant all privileges on database games to postgres;`. You can see in my third screenshot, that the access privileges changed. But this change did not do help me to solve the problem. I am still not able to see 'games' in pgAdmin. I saw someone had a similar problem and run the right click on the server and clicked 'New database'.

This seemed to created a new database, because as you can see from the pgAdmin, the application was able to find the score table I create inside pgAdmin. The reason I believe this is the case is, because running the same SQL connected to the server games=# select * from score; results in ERROR: relation "score" does not exist LINE 1: select * from score;.

[image]

Any other ideas where I went wrong. Would appreciate any help I can get.

I can log in to my database. When I run `psql games postgres`, this will log me into my games database with the postgres user. And this is also how I logged in and executed the select statement:

```
games=# select * from score;
```

> ERROR:  relation "score" does not exist
>   LINE 1: select * from score;

I went a step further I printed out the tables we have in 'games':

```
games=# \dt
```

> No relations found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you log into your games database using psql?

What I can see is that the first image has you connecting to localhost:5432, the second (the psql connection), you're connecting to jkalancic@vps73162 - on what appears to be a telnet session - are you sure that you're looking at the same database on the same machine?

[Following OP's answer]

A tip for next time - you could install from source and not be messing with /etc/postgresql - you can never be absolutely sure that you're not mixing clients, servers and ports unless you do this. I do this all the time for installs - on Linux and I see that you're on Ubuntu, so that should be a piece of cake.

PostgreSQL is really excellent for this kind of thing. Works first time straight - and you can tailor your prompt to point to your various installs - be sure to have a shutdown (in your startup script) if you want to put more than one server on port 5432.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to find the problems.

One was I had an installed PostgreSQL server on my machine that I was unaware of. It seems I installed it with my pgAdmin install. So every time I connected to my server, I would establish a connection to my localhost server and not my remote server. I just uninstalled the server and installed only the pgAdmin client.

The second problem I had was that the file `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf` had to be changed. So I ran:

```
sudo vi /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf
```

and changed the line

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local    all    postgres    peer
```

to

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local   all     postgres     md5
```

Once that was changed, I had two restart the configuration by executing:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/postgresql reload
```

I would also point out that it is important to have the postgres user as a unix and DB user with same passwords. I found all this information [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/PostgreSQL).